# System slow on new account creation

Tags: drupal, civimember

Civi 4.4.3
Drupal 7

When creating a new user account by signing up someone for a membership in CiviMember, the system appears to the user to hang.  The processing time is around 80 seconds while the civi account is created, matching drupal account created, card is processed, and other database stuff we are doing to set tags and the like.

Can anyone point me in the direction of any tips or tricks to optimize the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the CiviMember Roles Sync module enabled? The code in this is very similar to the other 'role sync' modules and is currently quite slow. There is an open issue about it here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14770

Otherwise you could try putting markers in your code at various points to see where the slow-down is happening. Or use a PHP profiling tool.

Comment: We do have roles sync enabled.

Comment: Try disabling it - see if that speeds things up - that should help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is that slow perhaps there is a slow mysql query & if you do a show processlist while it is happening you will spot it. My best guess would be a slow de-dupe rule is kicking in.

Be wary about including things with many matches in your dedupe rule - e.g. a city match will have many many pairings who match & will create load. Obviously an email mail is at the opposite end.